# finding counterexamples to proofs.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, proof-verification, proof-writing, cardinals

let f: A → B and let W, X ⊆ A.

Prove that if W ⊆ X, then g(W) ⊆ f(X)

I don't see how this can work, as I think I've found a counter example. Yet the instructions ask for a proof.

Let A = {0,1,2}

Let X = {0,1}

Let W = {0}

Then let f(x) = x+1  & let g(w) = w

Then g(0) = 0

f(0) = 1

f(1) = 2

So this satisfies all conditions, doesn't it? Yet, g(W) isn't a subset of f(X).   Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Is there any relationship between $f$ and $g$ at all? I have a feeling that you missed some part of the statement of the exercise.

Comment: I think you want to show that $f(W)\subset f(X)$.

Comment: What is g?  If g isn't defined this of course can very well not be true.

Comment: This is a counterexample to the problem you posed. Something appears to be missing.

Comment: Sorry, John Douma was correct. I didn't think about the importance of them being the same function.                                                                                     Let y \in f(w) be arbitrary. then there exist a w \in W s.t. f(w)=y. but since w is in W, w is in X since W is a subset of X. therefore f(w) is a subset of f(x)? Does this qualify as a proof?

Comment: Yes it's a proof.